# Azure app registrations - SQL Server permission for C# App

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I have created a C# app with an MSOL authentication prompt. This auth prompt authenticates the user to my app and to my Asana integration. This works fine.

I now need to give my app permissions to access SQL databases in my Azure App Registration, but I can't find the API listed in the "Request API Permissions" section.

Does anyone know how I am supposed to grant my app access to SQL? Currently I get an error from my app stating that it does not have access to the database. I have already set my AAD account as an admin of the DB but I still cannot access it.

Edit: This is the problem I am facing. Should be an option for SQL server.[image: Attempting to add SQL Server as an API permission]

Comment: Do you have access to the Server admin login?  I would try this or another SQL account first, then work up to AAD accounts.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.

For the Azure SQL Database option to show in the API Permissions you first need to create an Azure SQL Database and add yourself as either an admin or user and then login to that database via SQL Server Management Studio using Azure AD Credentials.

Once you have done that, the API still will not show without manually searching for "Azure SQL Database".

Microsoft should really make this stuff clear in their documentation.

Comment: I had a very similar problem trying to get the same API permission for a SQL managed instance - the only workaround I could find was to create an Azure SQL database as per this answer, just so the API would appear in API permissions.